# How can I get the images to scale with different screen sizes in Android Studio?

Tags: java, xml, imageview, android-constraintlayout

In my code my app runs fine, but I am running into issues when I am using a different screen size. The buttons line up correctly but the images do not scale at all.

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFC107"
        android:padding="40dp"
        tools:context=".ActivitiesActivity">

        <!-- ImageView Declarations -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_logo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/the_boiler_room"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/activity_alabama_music_hall_of_fame_card" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_FacebookButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_InstagramButton"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_InstagramButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_FacebookButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_WebsiteButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_WebsiteButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_InstagramButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_DirectionsButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_DirectionsButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_WebsiteButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame" />


        <!-- The Boiler Room ImageView -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/the_boiler_room"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/the_boiler_room_logo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/activity_the_boiler_room" />

        <!-- Buttons under The Boiler Room ImageView -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_boiler_room_FacebookButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/the_boiler_room"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/the_boiler_room_InstagramButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/the_boiler_room"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_boiler_room_InstagramButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/the_boiler_room"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/the_boiler_room_WebsiteButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/the_boiler_room_FacebookButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_boiler_room_WebsiteButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/the_boiler_room"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/the_boiler_room_DirectionsButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/the_boiler_room_InstagramButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_boiler_room_DirectionsButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/the_boiler_room"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/the_boiler_room"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/the_boiler_room_WebsiteButton" />


        <!-- The Escape Room ImageView -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/the_escape_room"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/the_escape_room_logo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/the_boiler_room"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/activity_the_escape_room" />

        <!-- Buttons under The Escape Room ImageView -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_escape_room_FacebookButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/the_escape_room"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/the_escape_room_InstagramButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/the_escape_room"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_escape_room_InstagramButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/the_escape_room"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/the_escape_room_WebsiteButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/the_escape_room_FacebookButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_escape_room_WebsiteButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/the_escape_room"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/the_escape_room_DirectionsButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/the_escape_room_InstagramButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_escape_room_DirectionsButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/the_escape_room"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/the_escape_room"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/the_escape_room_WebsiteButton" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have tried to set different constraints in the image view, I have tired

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="150dp"
```

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
```

Just about any different configuration I have tried, I feel like I am missing something basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, I used CardView inside of the ScrollView, which kept the images the same no matter the screen size. I also used a LinerLayout for my buttons so they would stay at the bottom of the image!

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFC107"
        android:padding="40dp"
        tools:context=".ActivitiesActivity">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_card"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/activity_alabama_music_hall_of_fame_card"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:contentDescription="@string/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_logo"/>
            <LinearLayout
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_FacebookButton"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/amhfFB"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_InstagramButton"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/amhfIG"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_WebsiteButton"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/amhfWeb"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_DirectionsButton"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/amhfDir"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/the_boiler_room_card"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/alabama_music_hall_of_fame_card"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/the_boiler_room"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/the_boiler_room_logo"
                android:src="@drawable/activity_the_boiler_room"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <LinearLayout
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/the_boiler_room_FacebookButton"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/tbrFB"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/the_boiler_room_InstagramButton"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/tbrIG"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/the_boiler_room_WebsiteButton"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/tbrWeb"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/the_boiler_room_DirectionsButton"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/tbrDir"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/the_escape_room_card"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/the_boiler_room_card"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activity_the_escape_room"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/the_escape_room_logo"
                android:src="@drawable/activity_the_escape_room"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <LinearLayout
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/the_escape_room_FacebookButton"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/terFB"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/the_escape_room_InstagramButton"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/terIG"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/the_escape_room_WebsiteButton"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/terWeb"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/the_escape_room_DirectionsButton"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/terDir"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>`
```